# LocalHost and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, localhost

I am trying to run MongoDB using a Node express application.
It runs fine for the first time..but once i close and start the code again, I get an error saying that localhost 3000 is already in use.
Also, connecting mongoDB gives an error stating that localhost port 27017 does not accept request

Comment: How are you "closing" the code? Is the process actually stopping?

Comment: The problem might be that the process is running in the background in your shell, depending on your OS and shell environment there are different ways to check this.

Comment: I am running the code through Command prompt...so once i enter npm start inside my application folder, the process gets started.
Then using Ctrl + C, i close it.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the command `npm start` it will run in background even after you close it using `Ctrl + C`. The process running in the background will block the port 3000, since it's being used.

Instead try running with the command `node app.js`. Change `app.js` for the main file of your server. (Restart the machine or kill the process before, so you can terminate the process created by your previous command `npm start` )

Another way to solve that problem is to manually kill the process started with the `npm start` command. `npm start` usually is used when the server is in production, since the command makes it run "forever".

Let me know if this solves your problem. :)

Comment: Hey thanks buddy...
Using node app.js is working perfectly.

Just in case, how do we kill the processes started with npm start manually?
Am a bit new to this

Comment: It depends on the OS your using. But take a look at this [ISSUE](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/1172), they explain how to do it for UNIX machines.